# Ng-Grid with Key Navigation

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs, can somebody help,
How can I navigate /select a row in a Grid using key press event.
Suppose for example when I press key X, row starting with X has to be selected.

can any one provide me working plunker or code

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ig3rpGVbVg2nX8uuqI5J?p=preview

Comment: Look at the documentation of ngGrid, all you need is explained there (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/). E.g. selecting rows: http://plnkr.co/edit/KemYS9?p=preview

Comment: selecting a grid row by key press is not available... @Rouby can you provide any working example...

Comment: Do you happen to know any javascript? If not I recommend learning it. This may sound harsh, but your question is too. "Please solve this problem for me with actual code.. btw I am not paying you." -.-

Comment: Have a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/yaN0Sr0Z4K7YZRrEBRvt?p=preview

Comment: Also have a look into this http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav